# Snakemake and sbatch

Tags: slurm, snakemake, sbatch

I have a Snakefile that has a rule which sends 7 different shell commands.
I want to run each of these shell commands in `sbatch` and I want them to run in different slurm nodes.
Right now when I include `sbatch` inside the shell command in the Snakemake rule I do not get the desired output file because it takes awhile to run and when `sbatch` returns the command is still running. I think Snakemake thinks that I don't have the required output file because it thinks that the command "finished executing" before the submitted job completed.

What can I do to submit each rule in one slurm node using sbatch command in Snakemake file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that what you are doing is:

```
rule one:
    input:
        ...
    output:
        ...
    shell:
        """
        sbatch [sbatch-options] "some-command-or-script"
        """
```

What you want maybe is:

```
rule one:
    input:
        ...
    output:
        ...
    shell:
        """
        some-command-or-script
        """
```

To be executed as

```
snakemake --cluster "sbatch [sbatch-options]"
```

In this way every rule will send its jobs to the cluster and snakemake will handle them. If you want a rule to execute  its jobs locally (not via sbatch) mark that rule with the directive `localrule` (check documentation for more detail)